# Why is History SE underlying in red "Habsburg" and tries to impose "Hapsburg"?

Tags: discussion, bug

While *Hapsburg* is correct in English (especially American, I think), academic works seem to prefer "Habsburg", which is the original form in German.

Looking up the term on Google books, all results include the b variant.

Here's a screen-shot of what I'm writing:

[image]

And searching "Hapsburg" on Google Books:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That will be the result of the language settings for the spell-check in your browser, not History:SE.

I'm using Chrome right now, and I see the same as you when I edit your question:

[image: History:SE]

This is because Chrome is set to use English(UK) on this PC:

[image: Settings]

So I will see the same thing on other sites. So for example., I typed Habsburg into the search box on Internet Archive:

[image: Internet Archive]

and got the same result.